# Phpmyadmin login denied

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using wamp. After setting up a password for my "root" "localhost" user in phpmyadmin the login screen reads: "#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" and it doesn't allow me to log in, neither does it ask me for a password...

I think I am supposed to add a password in wamp folder/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php but I don't know where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the following line in your config.inc.php and add the password there:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';
```

Comment: I don't have that line, can I create a new one anywhere in that ini?

Comment: @user2534840 I assume that you have other lines starting with $cfg['Servers'][$i]? Then just add it after this line: 

    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']

Comment: Thats not necessary with WampServer 2.4 and phpmyadmin 4.0.4

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the new WampServer 2.4 which includes phpmyadmin 4.0.4 then authentication has been changed to `cookie`.

This means phpmyadmin throws you a login page.

[image]

If this is your first time using it, the Userid = root and the password is blank ( nothing )

You can now add a password from the first page that loads after a successful login.

[image: phpmyadmin First page after successful login]

Once the password has been changed, your next access attempt will throw the login dialof again. User root and the new password.

Comment: the above instructions are OK but when i create a new user and try to login to phpmyAdmin, it gives error 1045 and i am unable to login using newly created user account. what to do?